# B2C Authentication in Azure Analysis Services

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-analysis-services

I have trouble linking my B2C AAD to Azure Analysis Services. Is this even possible? If yes, what's the best way to build it in?

The documentation states "Azure Analysis Services supports Azure AD B2B collaboration" but doesn't mention B2C. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

It is not listed in the release notes and a number of others have asked about this, so from what I can tell it does not appear to be supported. I have escalated your question to the Microsoft product group and will get back to you as soon as I have a definitive answer.

In the meantime you can make a feature request in User Voice. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/160596-b2c